# GCC compiler gives different results for Windows and Linux?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, bit

```
float i = 2.5f;
printf("%f, %d", floor(i), ceil(i));
```

This is giving output: 2.000000, some garbage value.
But for gcc 32-bit Linux platform answer is 2.000000,0
Why is that?

Comment: `ceil(i)` --> `(int)ceil(i)`, `%d` wants an `int`, or if you prefer switch to `%.0f` instead of `%d` to specify 0 decimals.

Comment: `ceil` returns a `double` but you're printing it with `%d`. This is undefined behaviour .Use `%f` for printing `ceil`'s return value.